# Chat badges for <20 rep users?

Tags: discussion, badges, chat

I was looking over the chat badges ([Talkative](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/884/talkative) and [Outspoken](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/998/outspoken)) since I just received one, and came across this oddity.

There are [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6998581/user895505) a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6996986/user1241255) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6996518/user3005549) who have both the *Talkative* and *Outspoken*, with only 1 point of reputation. This is strange as the chat feature of Stack Overflow states:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow chat! You'll need **20 reputation** to talk here

[image: Chat]

Clearly the users who have 1 rep shouldn't be able to chat, although have somehow received both the badges, which require at least 10 messages to be posted and one to be starred.

How is this possible?

Comment: @Tushar No recent reputation activity.

Comment: @Tunshar possibly, but all three users I've linked to, haven't posted to Stack Overflow at all

Comment: Room owners can add users as owners to the room, which gives them full access to the room, including posting there, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen for various reasons:

- User is suspended - but had chat privileges beforehand
- User is deleted - chat profile may still point to their account
- User has been given ownership in a room, meaning they can do anything there
- User gave away their reputation in bounties

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I count 5 users which fit my questions criteria on the first page of the Outspoken badge, and 2 pairs of these users received the badge at the exact same time on the exact same day, strange..

Comment: Note that users require at least 100 rep to be made an RO.

Comment: @JonClements - even if made so by another RO? I think not.

Comment: @luka - same time same day is not a surprise - badges are usually awarded in batches.

Comment: @Oded I'm sure that's the case...

Comment: The users I looked at (that the OP pointed to) were quite old, so could be from before that was a thing, @JonClements

Comment: @Oded ah yep you're right, completely forgot about that

Comment: Don't forget cases in which a user had enough rep to chat, but has given a lot of it away through bounties or lost it for other reasons, such as lots of downvoting of answers, deletion of posts, deletion of users who had voted up the user's content, or simple vote invalidation. Some users don't care about rep much except for using it to award bounties.

Comment: Wouldn't this happen too if users have 20 rep on other SE sites?

Comment: @DandanLee - depends on the chat server and what their configured parent site for chat is.